# Powershell: Setting SASS_BINARY_PATH

Tags: powershell, node-sass

I need to set SASS_BINARY_PATH environment variable with the local file I've downloaded to be able to install node-sass behind a corporate firewall. So on windows cmd, I just do:

```
SET SASS_BINARY_PATH=C:\Source\Repos\SRT\Srt.Web\sass-binary\v4.7.2\win32-x64-48_binding.node
```

And the installation works fine since it successfully sets the variable. But when I try doing it via Powershell, it doesn't work:

```
$env:SASS_BINARY_PATH="C:\Source\Repos\SRT\Srt.Web\sass-binary\v4.7.2\win32-x64-48_binding.node"
```

I've also tried another way on Powershell:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("SASS_BINARY_PATH", "C:\Source\Repos\SRT\Srt.Web\sass-binary\v4.7.2\win32-x64-48_binding.node", "Machine")
```

Upon checking it on the control panel, it successfully added a "SASS_BINARY_PATH" system variable. But upon trying to reinstall node-sass, it fails again.

One of my observations is when I'm doing it the windows cmd way then check it by using the command line `set`, the variable shows up along with others. But when I use both the Powershell methods, it does not show up. Any ideas on this?

The error encountered when trying to npm-install node-sass over a corporate firewall is:

> Downloading binary from
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7
>   .2/win32-x64-48_binding.node Cannot download
>   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win3
>   2-x64-48_binding.node":
>
> HTTP error 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Did you try with [this](http://sass-lang.com/install) instruction for windows?
You need to install Ruby and then install SASS gem package

Comment: I haven't tried installing ruby and via gem because I want it to be installed on npm so that It can be automatically triggered on Jenkins.

Comment: so did you try `npm install node-sass` then? if yes what happened?

Comment: as I have explained above, it fails since it cannot find the sass_binary_path when I try to use the powershell methods.

Comment: That is not enough I guess, can you put the full error message when try to execute `npm install node-sass`

Comment: just updated the question for the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159841/discussion-between-jengfad-and-dwij).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Download win32-x64-48_binding.node manually
- Put it in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.7.2` folder.
- Then try to run `npm install node-sass`

here is the PowerShell command @jengfad used based on above solution which is commented in the discussion

```
$cacheSassPath = $env:APPDATA + '\npm-cache\node-sass' 

if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $cacheSassPath ) ) 
{ 

Write-Host "cacheSassPath not exists" 

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $cacheSassPath 
Write-Host "cacheSassPath CREATED" 
} 

<# Ensure has no content #> 
Get-ChildItem -Path $cacheSassPath -Recurse| Foreach-object {Remove-item -Recurse -path $_.FullName } 

<# Copy local sass binary (~Srt.Web\sass-binary\4.7.2) file to cache folder #> 
$sassBinaryPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$sassBinaryPath = $sassBinaryPath + "\sass-binary\4.7.2" 

Copy-Item -Path $sassBinaryPath -Recurse -Destination $npmcachedir -Container 

Write-Host "node-sass binary file successfully copied!"
```